# AngularJS remote client Properties share to controllers/services

Tags: angularjs, rest

I want to develop an AngularJS web client for which the REST backend may be located on a different server. 
So basically I am thinking of having a property input field on the frontend where for each session I will enter the base REST url (e.g., `http://localhost:8080/backend/rest/`)

Is there some sort of best practice to be able to share the base url amongst all controller/factories/services in order to include it for all $http requests?

Answer (score 2):

I would configure an [HTTP request interceptor](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) service that would simply prepend the value to the URL passed to the $http service. Something like the following (not tested):

```
// register the interceptor as a service
$provide.factory('pathPrependerInterceptor', function() {
    var _path = 'http://localhost:8080/backend/rest'; // default value
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            config.url = _path + config.url
            return config;
        },
        setPath: function(path) {
            _path = path;
        }
    }
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('pathPrependerInterceptor');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the bast way would be to acomplish this with the use of `interceptors`. You can read more about this topic in the [AngularJs documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http).

The idea is to set up an interceptor that will preappend the base url to each request something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                config.url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/" + config.url
                return config;
            }
        };
    });
}]);
```

I hope you got an idea.

There is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/3122/) that incorporates this idea.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are from a more experienced bunch, so take this with a pinch of salt, but they seem like overkill to me. You're configuring an application-wide variable which needs injection. Using

```
module.value("baseRestUrl", ...)
```

lets you inject `baseRestUrl` wherever it's required.